# Nested one-to-many relationships in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

So I am creating an LMS system, and I have tried executing the code below to insert a deeply nested relational structure into the database. Once I executed the code I received an error. What have I done wrong in this instance?

`code:`

```py
async def create_program(db: AsyncSession, program: ProgramSchema) -> Program:
    new_program = Program(title=program.title, slug=program.slug)
    new_courses = []
    new_lessons = []
    new_sections = []

    for course in program.courses:
        new_course = Course(title=course.title, slug=course.slug)
        for lesson in course.lessons:
            new_lesson = Lesson(title=lesson.title, slug=lesson.slug)
            for section in lesson.sections:
                new_section = Section(
                    title=section.title,
                    slug=section.slug,
                    body=section.body,
                )
                new_lesson.sections.append(new_section)
                new_sections.append(new_section)
            new_course.lessons.append(new_lesson)
            new_lessons.append(new_lesson)
        new_program.courses.append(new_course)
        new_courses.append(new_course)
    db.add(new_program)
    db.add_all(new_courses)
    db.add_all(new_lessons)
    db.add_all(new_sections)
    await db.commit()
    await db.refresh(new_program)
    return new_program
```

`error`

```
This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/xd2s) (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/7s2a)
./repositories/database_repository.py:24: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncSession.rollback' was never awaited
  session.rollback()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

`Models:`

```py
class Program(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    slug = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    courses = relationship("Course", backref="program")
    created_on = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False
    )
    updated_on = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True),
        default=datetime.utcnow,
        onupdate=datetime.utcnow(),
        nullable=False,
    )


class Course(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    slug = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    program_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("program.id"))
    lessons = relationship("Lesson", backref="course")
    likes = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    dislikes = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    created_on = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False
    )
    updated_on = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True),
        default=datetime.utcnow,
        onupdate=datetime.utcnow(),
        nullable=False,
    )


class Lesson(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    slug = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    course_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("course.id"))
    sections = relationship("Section", backref="lesson")
    likes = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    dislikes = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    created_on = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False
    )
    updated_on = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True),
        default=datetime.utcnow,
        onupdate=datetime.utcnow(),
        nullable=False,
    )


class Section(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    slug = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    body = Column(String, nullable=True)
    lesson_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("lesson.id"))
    likes = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    dislikes = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    created_on = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False
    )
    updated_on = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True),
        default=datetime.utcnow,
        onupdate=datetime.utcnow(),
        nullable=False,
    )
```

`Structure:`

`Program`>`List of Courses`>`List of Lessons`> `List of Sections`

Comment: The error you've included is only the last symptom; the actual error is caused by something higher up in your stack (the rollback is probably issued because the server returns a 500 error)

Comment: Is your session configured to handle multiple inserts? (It could be that the db is transacting one insert at a time.)

Comment: I will take a look at the configuration. @YaakovBressler. MatsLindh I took a look and I forgot to await the rollback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `, lazy="immediate"` in the relationship function and it worked.